# When working with block, How to store data into an mutable array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

The code to get image data is :

```
// assume there are 10 images
__block NSMutableArray *aArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

[self.imageManager requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                                    options:nil
                              resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData,NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info){
    cell.thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                                  [aArray addObject:imageData];   
                              }];
```

I am trying to store 'imageData' into 'aArray'.But the result turn out to be 10 empty mutable array.

Comment: So, first off, you are returning NSDictionary *info, which looks like a single object, am I right? If this is a single object, then that's part of the problem, plus, if you want to store this in an array, you would need to use like a for loop and add an object at each loop index

Comment: Yes, and as I suspected, this is for a PHAsset, and as such, you would have to loop through this same entire method before the __block in order to store images into that array, so you would need a list of "assets" and then loop though storing them as objects into the mutable array

Comment: @Larcerax Why is 'info' a problem here?

Comment: @Larcerax But the request method didn't return any thing, did you mean loop in the block? Can you show me some example? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's not a problem, it's just that the "info" variable points to a single PHAsset, so you would need to call the entire method above a bunch of times change the "asset" variable,

Comment: there's a typo `aArray` vs `array`

Comment: @vadian edited thanks

Comment: There is no point in using `__block` here, since you never assign to `aArray `

Comment: @newacct `[aArray addObject:imageData];` I thought this will add an new object  to the array.Can you tell me the correct way to assign to `aArray`?

Comment: @xxkkk: You never assign to `aArray`. Assignment means `aArray = something;` You are simply reading the value of the pointer variable `aArray` and using that to send a message.

Comment: @newacct the correct way?

Comment: @xxkkk: Just remove the `__block`. It is useless.